# What is the word "Heavens" used for?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does the highlighted words [outside of the physical universe] mean?

[image]

Does it refer to 'the dimensionless space '?

Comment: What are the blanked out words?

Comment: @ James K  The blanked out words are the reference. Since I wasn't sure of them being quoted correctly thus blanked these out.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the source is really the one mentioned in these.

Comment: It means "a place you cannot imagine." Any attempt at a concrete definition is futile, although it does imply "better than here".

Answer (score 0):

> Does it refer to 'the dimensionless space '?

That is hard to say, as we cannot (yet) "measure" anything in that area. I can think of three possibilities, from this point of view:

1. It could be "dimensionless" as you say (this might include anything which is less than 3 dimensions).
2. It could be "multi-dimensioned" - more than 3 dimensions. As of now, we cannot know / imagine for sure even how a 4 dimensional space could look like. There are some attempts to guess how a projection from the 4-dimension world would look like in our 3D world.
3. It is entirely parallel, regardless of the number of dimensions.

---

To come back to the base question. We call "physical" anything that can be seen / touched with our limited sense organs (even if we need special devices for that, e.g. microscopes). Therefore, "outside of the physical universe" refers to everything which exists but cannot be perceived with our sense organs.

I guess that the electromagnetic waves are somewhere between the two worlds: physical and non-physical. We cannot touch these waves, but:

- we can see a limited spectrum of the electromagnetic waves (what we call visible light);
- we can see their effects:

  - tanning of the skin (UV-light);
  - killing of germs (UV-C light);
  - listening to music and news (radio, TV)
  - live communications (GSM, satellite etc...)
  - etc.

It must e noted though that electro-magnetic waves were proven to behave both as waves (pure energy, non-"physical") and as particles (physical nature). This adds to my statement that "electromagnetic waves are somewhere between the two worlds".

---

I should be noted that in the context of the text, the "spirit realm" is "outside of the physical universe", but it does not imply sine-qua-non that the "spirit realm" is the only thing "outside of the physical universe". There might be other "realms", but there is no reference to them.

Comment: From this point of view, the entire thing about "spiritual" is confusing, starting with the definition of "exists". To make it easy to grasp: does God (the ultimate spiritual being) exist or not?

Comment: does *i* (the square root of -1) exist? Does it matter? Are scientists defending it and theists challenging it? If it works, then it *might as well* exist. It's a stepping-stone that allows one to get from A to B in ways that might otherwise be difficult or impossible. Obviously it **isn't real** but that does not make it worthless.